# How do I write a jasmine expectation that a function has returned when an input parameter is null?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following javascript function:

```
function(fieldObject, value) {

    if (!value) {
      return;
    }

    // call some other functions
}
```

Is it possible to write an expectation that the function gets returned in the if statement without writing multiple expectations that all the other functions after the if statement are not called?

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty interesting question:
I'm not 100% sure if there is a way to achieve what you are seeking, however I have used this trick to verify the state of early return (like in your case)

Here us how I used it-

- Make your `void` methods `return false` to exit the processing. You may
  not use this return value in the code but you can sure test it
  efficiently.
- If your method is is expected to return a value yet it has an early return/break, you could still break it with `return false`.

Code sample to illustrate the above scenarios:

```
var testObj = {
    voidLikeFunction : function(arg1){
        if(!arg1){
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log('Executes void like function..');
            this.callAFunction();
            this.callAnotherFunction();
            this.callYetAnotherFunction();
        }
    },

    callAFunction : function(){
        console.log('callAFunction()');
    },

    callAnotherFunction : function(){
        console.log('callAnotherFunction()');
    },

    callYetAnotherFunction : function(){
        console.log('callYetAnotherFunction()');
    },

    expectedToReturnInt : function(arg1){
        if(!arg1){
            return false
        } else {
            var sum =0;
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                sum += i;
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
};

describe('testVoidLikeFunc', function(){
    it('testEarlyReturn', function(){
        var val = testObj.voidLikeFunction();
        expect(val).toBe(false);
    });
    it('testLateReturn', function(){
        spyOn(testObj, 'callAFunction').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(testObj, 'callAnotherFunction').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(testObj, 'callYetAnotherFunction').and.callThrough();
        var dummyParam = true;
        testObj.voidLikeFunction(dummyParam);
        expect(testObj.callAFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(testObj.callAnotherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(testObj.callYetAnotherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});

describe('testExpectedToReturnInt', function(){
    it('testEarlyReturn', function(){
        var val = testObj.expectedToReturnInt();
        expect(val).toBe(false);
    });
    it('testLateReturn', function(){
        var dummyParam = true;        
        var val = testObj.expectedToReturnInt(dummyParam);
        expect(val).toEqual(45);
    });
});
```